# tab bar controller and segue navigation

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, segue

could somebody explain me the logic?

I have the following structure:

[image]

In VC1("Item1") I have a table. Table's cell is connected with VC2("Item") with segue to pass some variables to VC2. This part works fine. After pressing table's cell it brings me to VC2.

What I don't understand is why tab view controller in the bottom is indicating that I am still on the VC1?

[image]

And why I can even press VC2 on tab controller("Item") and it will show it but without passed variables (of course it should not show variables).

Comment: Why do you need VC2 linked to the tabController if it needs data from vc1 for it to even work?

Comment: Well initial idea is to show more specified data from selected cell. And if it is accessed from tab controller - it would show more general data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the app loads up the tab bar, one instance of VC2 is instantiated. When you perform the segue another instance is instantiated and thrown on the navigation stack that is tab1. At this point you never left the first tab. When you click the second tab you are looking at the original instance of VC2 that is missing the data that was passed through the segue.

Comment: If I was doing this I would have a NSNotification listener in the class that manages the tab bar (usually appdelegate). When the data is obtained from VC1 I would call the notification and pass it whatever data objects are needed. That class (usually appdelegate) would hear the notification, access the data objects, and manually navigate to the VC2 tab. Since this class has access the the correct instance it can pass the necessary data though.

Comment: thanks for clarification! is it possible to perform segue to existing instance of VC2? maybe in prepareforsegue method I need to use   let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! self.SecondViewController